# how to inject a jsp page into a div on click event in spring mvc

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, path

i want to **load** or **inject** a jsp page into a **div** when clicking on link

i have tried the below code to do so

```
<script>    
 $(document).ready(function() {
        var contextPath="<%=request.getContextPath()%>";  

        $("#stuAdmn").click(function(){
            $("#pageContent").load(contextPath+"/WEB-INF/views/studentAdmission.jsp");  

        });   

    }); 
</script>
```

it gives following error

```
GET http://localhost:8015/campasAdmin/WEB-INF/views/studentAdmission.jsp 404 (Not Found)
```

even i tried like this

.jsp

```
<c:set var="url">${pageContext.request.requestURL}</c:set>  
 <c:set var="baseURL" value="${fn:replace(url, pageContext.request.requestURI,  pageContext.request.contextPath)}" />
```

java script

```
$("#stuAdmn").click(function(){
            $("#pageContent").load("${baseURL}/studentAdmission.jsp");  

        });
```

it gives same error. how to achieve this in spring mvc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not access anything under the `WEB-INF` folder directly.

But you can forward a request from a `Controller` to the `JSP` page.

If you already have the `InternalViewResourceResolver` configured for the JSPs, then add a new `RequestMapping` which forwards to your JSP and use this `URL` in the `jQuery` `load` method.

You can add this `Controller` to return the `studentAdmission.jsp`.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/studentAdmission")
public class StudentAdmissionController{

   @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public String studentAdmission() {
      return "studentAdmission";
   }
}
```

Now you can use the URL of the controller `/studentAdmission` in your `load` method

Comment: i did not get can you please give small example this how my config is `<bean
  class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
  <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
  <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />     
 </bean> `

Comment: i am doing the same but ca't we do it without controller

Comment: @bharath you can do it without a controller, by keeping the JSP outside of WEB-INF folder.i.e. directly inside your web folder and do the necessary configuration to serve the JSP from there. But the above mentioned way is the standard. You really don't want the user to know that you are using JSP as your view technology and this is inline with the MVC principle